# Is Visual Studio 2013 Missing "Remote Site" as a Option Within the "Copy Web Site" Feature?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2012 when you "copy web site" (in VS 2013 > Website > Copy Web Site) and you click on the Connect button the interface used to have File System / Local IIS / FTP Site / and "Remote Site". This was used to connect to sites with Front Page Server Extensions. I still have one client on a server that I support that is using this. Is there a way within VS 2013 to still accomplish this or do I need to keep a copy of VS 2012 around for this feature?

Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Front Page was removed in VS2013.  You'll need to keep a copy of VS2012 around for this.